# Почему у меня происходит утечка памяти? всего 3 класса

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет, c3p0

У меня есть главный поток`(main(String [] args))` , в нем есть

```
while(true){
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress());
        //Когда есть новое подключение запускаю новый поток для работы с ним
        new SecondSocket(socket).start();
    }
```

Есть еще один класс в ней настройка `c3p0`

```
public class DatabaseUtility {
    static String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://blablabla";
    public static ComboPooledDataSource getDataSource() throws PropertyVetoException{

        ComboPooledDataSource c = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        c.setJdbcUrl(connectionUrl);
        c.setInitialPoolSize(3);
        c.setMinPoolSize(3);
        c.setAcquireIncrement(3);
        c.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        c.setMaxStatements(500);

        return c;
    }

}
```

И классе `new SecondSocket(socket).start();` Создаю `CallableStatement` :

```
    CallableStatement cstmt = null;//эту же ссылку использую еще в двух местах
                //т.е. 3 объекта CallableStatement 
                cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{call xml_parser(?,?)}");
                cstmt.setString(1, line);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
                cstmt.execute();
```

Где я не правильно делаю? если связь с клиентом обрывается созданный поток `new SecondSocket(socket).start();` он должен исчезнуть из `хипа`?На заметку метод `run()` свою работу завершает.Хочу узнать в каком из них проблема в `c3p0` или в `SecondSocket(socket).start()` или в `Socket()`?

Comment: По-моему это все нужно решать отладкой. По куску кода вряд ли кто то сможет понять в чем проблема.

Comment: @coder675 ясно.спасибо.

Comment: ServerSocket вроде реализует Closable... Может быть, его ресурсы надо явно освобождать методом close(), когда он становится не нужен, включая ситуации с исключением? (try-finally, try с ресурсами)

Comment: @velial но ServerSocket он же просто фабрика..или вы имеете в виду закрывать Socket?

Comment: Да, закрывать Socket... Ошибся чуток